# Add an element to listB without adding it to listA in java

Tags: java, list

I have two list (listA and listB) and I want them to be independent. So I can add an element to the listB without the elements of the listA being modified, to remain the same.

Tryed Collection listB = Collections.unmodifiableCollection(listA);

```
    ArrayList<String> listA = new ArrayList<>();
    listA.add("alex");
    listA.add("brian");
    listA.add("charles");
    ArrayList<String> listB = new ArrayList<>();
    listB = listA;
    listB.add("williams");
    System.out.println(listA);
```

run:
[alex, brian, charles, williams]

When I run it I wanted to show only theese
run:
[alex, brian, charles]
(Without "williams")

Comment: You should clone `listA` as `listB`, before adding to `listB`

Answer (score 5):

When you are doing `listB = listA` you are just assigning the reference of listA to listB, you are not creating a new Object.
 To create a new Object, do a copy of the list as below

```
List<String> listB = new ArrayList<>(listA);
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to add all elements of a List to another, you may simply use the method addAll.

In your case:

```
listB.addAll(listA);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    ArrayList<String> listA = new ArrayList<>();
    listA.add("alex");
    listA.add("brian");
    listA.add("charles");
    ArrayList<String> listB = (ArrayList<String>) listA.clone();
    listB.add("williams");
    System.out.println(listA);
    System.out.println(listB);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SerializationUtils.clone() method.

```
private static void deepCopy(){
    ArrayList<String> listA = new ArrayList<>();
    listA.add("alex");
    listA.add("brian");
    listA.add("charles");
    ArrayList<String> listB = SerializationUtils.clone(listA);
    listB.add("williams");
    System.out.println(listA);
    System.out.println(listB);

}
```

Result:

```
[alex, brian, charles]
[alex, brian, charles, williams]
```

Comment: and where is this class `SerializationUtils` class defined? a reference link to docs might be encouraged...

Comment: It's include in "commons-lang<version>.jar" .First add that jar as the dependency and after that, import the 'import org.apache.commons.lang3.SerializationUtils'

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is how clone `List` in Java,there are many method to do this:

- **Using a Copy Constructor:** Using the ArrayList constructor in Java, a new list can be initialized with the elements from another collection.

```java
List<String> listB = new ArrayList<>(listA);
```

- **Using the addAll() method:** The List class has a method called addAll(), which appends all the elements of one collection to the list.

```java
List<String> listB = new ArrayList<>();
listB.addAll(listA);
```

- **Using streams in Java 8** Using the [Streams API introduced in JAVA 8](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stream-in-java/), cloning of a list is possible. The collect() method (along with [toList()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/collectors-tolist-method-in-java-with-examples/) method) is used to clone a list.

```java
List<String> listB = listA.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

- **Using Gson library to convert list to JSON**: Using Google’s Gson library, a list can be converted to JSON. This JSON string can be converted to an object of type List and can be used to initialize the new List.

```java
String jsonListA = gson.toJson(listA);
List<String> listB = gson.fromJson(jsonListA,List.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the original list to a new object. You can stream the first list and collect the elements in a new one:

```
List<String> listB = listA.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Please notice that using a copy constructor (like `new ArrayList<>(listA)`) or using the **addAll** method, the contents of both lists will reference the same objects, every amends made in one element will affect both lists.